# Разработка приложения для шлема Epoc Emotiv

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте, нужна помощь в разработке приложения для шлема. В течении нескольких дней не получается переписать код в windows forms,пишу в "visual studio2012, С++". Суть, заключается в том что в консольном приложении CLR работает на ура.

пишу в консоли.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include "edk.h"
#include "edkErrorCode.h"
#include "EmoStateDLL.h"
#include <list>

using namespace System;

#pragma comment(lib, "../lib/edk.lib")

using namespace std;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{

EmoEngineEventHandle hEvent = EE_EmoEngineEventCreate();

    EmoStateHandle eState = EE_EmoStateCreate();
    unsigned int userID = -1;
    list<int> listUser;

    if( EE_EngineConnect() == EDK_OK )
    {
        while(!_kbhit()) 
        {
            int state = EE_EngineGetNextEvent(hEvent);
            if( state == EDK_OK )
            {
                EE_Event_t eventType = EE_EmoEngineEventGetType(hEvent);                
                EE_EmoEngineEventGetUserId(hEvent, &userID);
                if(userID==-1)
                    continue;

                if(eventType == EE_EmoStateUpdated  )
                {                                
                    // Copies an EmoState returned with a EE_EmoStateUpdate event to memory referenced by an EmoStateHandle. 
                    if(EE_EmoEngineEventGetEmoState(hEvent,eState)==EDK_OK)
                    {
                        if(EE_GetUserProfile(userID,hEvent)==EDK_OK)
                        {
                            //Affective score, short term excitement                        
                            cout <<"userID: " << userID  <<endl;
                            cout <<"    affectiv excitement score: " << ES_AffectivGetExcitementShortTermScore (eState) << endl;
                            cout <<"    expressiv smile extent : " << ES_ExpressivGetSmileExtent(eState) <<endl;                            
                        }

                    }

                }
                // userremoved event
                else if( eventType == EE_UserRemoved )
                {
                    cout <<"user ID: "<<userID<<" have removed" << endl;    
                    listUser.remove(userID);
                }
                // useradded event 
                else if(eventType == EE_UserAdded)
                {
                    listUser.push_back(userID);
                    cout <<"user ID: "<<userID<<" have added" << endl;
                }        
                userID=-1;
            }            
        }
    }

    EE_EngineDisconnect();
    EE_EmoStateFree(eState);
    EE_EmoEngineEventFree(hEvent);    
    return 0;
}
```

Когда пишу в windows forms, библиотеки подключаю таким образом

```
#include "edk.h"
#include "edkErrorCode.h"
#include "EmoStateDLL.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "../lib/edk.lib")
```

Далее пишу 
EmoEngineEventHandle hEvent ; всё работает нормально , Но стоит присвоить 
hEvent = EE_EmoEngineEventCreate();

Выходить ошибка
не удалось создать P или Invoke для "extern "C" void * __clrcall EE_EmoEngineEventCreate(void)" (?EE_EmoEngineEventCreate@@$$J0YMPAXXZ); в метаданных отсутствует соглашение о вызовах

Может надо по другому библиотеки подключать ? Отдельным классом реализовать ? Или в консоль можно добавить форму. Идея появилась, консоль парсить, и уже в форме обрабатывать полученные данные.